# How to pass props from TabNavigator to StackNavigator in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

There are 2 StackNavigator objects with few screens inside a TabNavigator. How to pass props from App.js -> TabNavigator -> each StackNavigator -> screen?

Code below generates errors, saying that only one router can be rendered.

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: props => <SettingsScreen {...props} screenProps={{is_authenticated: props.is_authenticated}}/> },
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});

const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    SettingsStack: {screen: props => <SettingsStack {...props} screenProps={{is_authenticated: props.is_authenticated}}/>},
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was removing all props-passing techniques and using screenProps. It turned out that when you have hierarchy such as AppComponent -> TabNavigator -> StackNavigator -> HomeComponent, where "->" means "includes" or "renders", there is no need to pass screenProps from TabNavigator to StackNavigator explicitly, because screenProps are passed within 2 navigators by default.

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow provide a way to pass in properties into the navigator object. Perhaps your function could work like this:

```
function createNav (props) {
  // Do something
  return createStackNavigator({
    Settings: {screen: <SettingsScreen {...props})
  })
}
```

In your example, the you have screen as a function passing props to the component. But how does it know where to get those props from?

Another very straightforward option for basic props would be to pass a [property with navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html#docsNav). In this case, you basically call `navigate('screen', {property: 'value'})` during navigation and then use

```
const val = navigation.getParam('property', 'defaultValue') // 'value'
```

to get it out in the screen you are navigating to.